# coffeescript array finding next position

Tags: javascript, arrays, coffeescript

I have an array setup like the following:

```
services = ['times', 'food', 'messages', 'share']
```

And I would like to be able to pass into services 'times' and have it return the next position in the array i.e. 'food'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
nextPos = services.indexOf('times');
```

This is JS, but also valid in CoffeeScript. Note, though, that if used outside of CofeeScript, it's an ECMA5 addition, so won't work in older browsers (EDIT - as the comment says, this of course means IE <= 8).

Comment: More specifically, it won't work in IE 8 and below. [Reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf)

Comment: I would do `nextPost = services.indexOf 'times'` to make it more CS-esque

Comment: This is not valid CoffeeScript.  `var` isn't a legal token.

Answer (score 1):

Based on **Utkanos** answer but in CS:

```
getNext = (arr, key) ->
    arr[arr.indexOf(key) + 1]
console.log getNext services, 'times' # food
```